# Is there a document which compiles all spells into one list, organised by class?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e

I am trying to find a file which contains a properly organised spell list for the sake of choosing spells more easily rather than going through every book I own to find them

Comment: Is there something wrong with the online resources?

Comment: Not inherently but I use devices which don't have constant access to the internet, plus the online resources are a tad bit confusing to use on mobile

Comment: @KorvinStarmast This question is tagged pathfinder 1e not D&D 5e. Pathfinder has dozens of official sources that contain spells, so players seeking out a centralized source isn't uncommon. And d20pfsrd.com is far from being mobile friendly.

Comment: @That_Knight_Guy whoops, sorry. 

Comment: The easiest thing might be to download the database from Nethys to a spreadsheet on your own cloud/device. Although you'll likely only fit summaries and have to find the books associated for full rules